# Como proteger unos archivos properties y persistence.xml dentro de un jar?

Tags: java, seguridad, jar

Me podrían ayudar por favor es que al generar el jar de mi aplicación empaqueta tambien la informacion de la base de datos (`Persistence.xml`) junto a unos [archivo-de-propiedades](/questions/tagged/archivo-de-propiedades) `.properties` y esto hace que la aplicacion sea muy vulnerable, quisiera saber como hago para impedir esto para añadirle seguridad a dichos archivos.

Comment: Hola Sebastian. Ya preguntaste sobre [Como cifrar un Jar ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108611/15855) y fue cerrada.. si es a lo que te referias en la otra pregunta deberias editarla para mejorarla y no hacer una nueva. Un saludo

Comment: ¿Por qué es vulnerable? Es decir, es una aplicación que corre en un servidor, no? (Si tiene acceso directo a una base de datos tiene que ser así, o tienes un problema de diseño grave)

Answer (score 0):

Contestaré tu pregunta ya que se me ocurre un caso en particular en el que el atacante no tendría acceso a tu ambiente del servidor donde corre tu aplicación, pero sí a tu repositorio de código, aunque seguramente hay mejores formas de hacerlo.

1. Asegurate de tener [jasypt](/questions/tagged/jasypt) en tu classpath, lo puedes hallar en http://www.jasypt.org/
2. Abre el comando encrypt.sh o encrypt.batsegún tu plataforma y corre el script con los parámetros de la forma `input=LOQUEQUIERESENCRIPTAR password=FRASESECRETA algorithm=PBEWITHMD5ANDDES`, te generará una cadena de este estilo `AbcVQvbRzZJ7uw00CahB3Q==`
3. asumiendo que usas hibernate, modifica tu persistence de la siguientemanera

   ```
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="ENC(AbcVQvbRzZJ7uw00CahB3Q==)"/>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.jasypt.hibernate.connectionprovider.EncryptedPasswordC3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.encryptor_registered_name" value="hibernateEncryptor"/>
   ```
4. Registra el encriptador en tu contexto

   ```
   EnvironmentStringPBEConfig config = new EnvironmentStringPBEConfig();
   config.setPasswordEnvName("MY_SECRET");

   StandardPBEStringEncryptor strongEncryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
   strongEncryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWITHMD5ANDDES");
   strongEncryptor.setConfig(config);

   HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry registry =  HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry.getInstance();
   registry.registerPBEStringEncryptor("hibernateEncryptor", strongEncryptor);
   ```
5. ahora toca agregar una variable de ambiente que esté de acuerdo al código anterior, es decir que se llame `MY_SECRET`
6. Suponiendo que te preocupe que alguien entre a tu servidor y robe esa conraseña de tu variable de ambiente, una vez iniciada tu aplicación puedes borrarla sin problemas

Fuente: https://rajnarayanamurthy.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/protect-passwords-in-config-files/